# Are requests for concept suggestions good questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732148/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-to-ms-sql-2008-database) was in the Triage queue, I am surprised no one tried to edit or down-vote it. I didn't do it myself because I wanted to see other people's opinion. Although I would really like cleaning it up (editing it), but I contained myself because I don't want to render useless (by getting them disputed) any flags other users my apply since I am unsure this question is a good fit for SO.

The OP is not asking for us to give him code to solve his problem, but wants a suggestion of the best way to go about solving it. 
I have seen other questions similar to this on SO, and sometimes they get closed/down-voted and other times they even get up-votes, this seems a grey area to me. I know it all depends on who looks at the posts, and as consequence even a question that is not a good fit for SO could get good feedback, so I want to get advise on what is the "recommended" course of action with questions like this.

Is a question that requests a concept, not code, but an idea on how to do something, a good question for SO?

Comment: Not remotely. It falls squarely under the "too broad" close-vote option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you see the phrases "best way", "best practice", or anything else that seems like it could encompass a lot, it's usually a good sign that what they're asking is too broad in scope.

There are a lot of ways to do something, and there are a lot of "best" ways to go about a solution; what a question that asks one of those questions would invite is a lot of discussion with little hard evidence.

Comment: Thanks Makoto! So how would you go about questions like this? Would you down-vote besides flagging as too broad?

Comment: There's no definitive pattern that I apply when voting; I generally reserve judgment if I feel like the question has a chance at being reopened.

Comment: Ok, then I just wanted to validate "best practices" I prefer voting to close than down-voting in cases like this. I was just wondering if one could have an effect in the other, like are down-voted questions more likely to be closed than the same quality question but without down-votes?

Comment: Both VTC and downvotes play a role in a person's question/answer ban on the site.  But I would strongly encourage you to think about the content and vote objectively based on your own opinion.  It's *clear* that the question needs to be put on hold, but the vote is entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks again, I hand't thought on the impact voting and closing has on banning. I always consider carefully when to down-vote. I don't want users to feel harassed and discouraged from using the site by receiving a closing and down-voting spree when they were just being naive or didn't have clear certain things. In this case I felt the question was too broad as pointed out by @AndrewArnold, but I have seen similar questions received a different treatment so I wanted to make sure for future reference. As always your insights are very useful, thanks.

Comment: Its been answered but also consider this: if it WERE a valid SO question, then it would almost definitely have been a duplicate as this is not exactly an uncommon requirement. Which would make it a close vote again :)

Answer (score -5):

> Is a question that requests a concept, not code, but an idea on how to
>   do something, a good question for SO?

**If the answer to this question was "no", we could just as well delete 99% of the questions tagged as "algorithm".** An example: [How to pair socks from a pile efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently). Currently it has a score of 2435, it has been favourited 1081 times, viewed 255384 times, and it is protected. And the top answer has a score of 1558. Is it a bad question? No way. Should it be closed as "too broad", as somebody suggested? Again, no way. And yet, the OP didn't ask for code. He asked for an idea. And most answers do not give any code at all; some do, but it's pseudocode.

That's the key: **if somebody asks for a concept, it simply means he basically wants pseudocode, without dealing with the syntax of a specific language.** He can, and will, deal with the implementation, in his language of choice; he just doesn't know how to approach the problem.

So why is the question I have linked an excellent one, and why are others terrible? He even explicitly asked "what is the best way to...?", which according to Makoto's rule of thumb is a sign that the question could be too broad. I couldn't disagree more.

I will go even further: actually, questions which seek an idea and not code are often much better than others. More interesting, at least. Because instead of concentrating on the quirks of a language and to fight against its syntax and its limitations, you can concentrate on the core of the problem. Which is the part that I like about programming - certainly better than struggling to get a C++ pointer to pointer to work. Or a Perl array of references to hashes of arrays, or that sort of things.

The only thing I could say against these questions is that someone might feel they belong to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. The difference between SO and Programmers SE is not really clear to me, so I don't know. Oh, by the way: if questions about concepts were bad, that entire site (Programmers SE) could be deleted without hesitation.

And to add one more thing: the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says (emphasis mine) that

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in
>   them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - **a software algorithm**, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the
>   right place to ask your question!

Ok, they mention "a bit of source code", but they also mention the rest.

...**In short: a question that requests a concept, not code, can be a great question**. Of course it could also be a very bad one, but that depends on the single question, not on its asking for ideas instead of code.

Comment: In fairness, the question you linked was posted on reddit at one point in its life and the votes are a result of that, not necessarily the community's views.  While I like these types of questions because they make you think, they belong on Programmers and not  Stack Overflow

Comment: [Your example falls apart.  Discussing algorithms is on-topic for Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Makoto: So you are telling me that discussing algorithms is on topic, and to support it you are quoting the Help Center? Interesting, because it is exactly what I have written (including quoting the Help Center!), and it contradicts your own answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 then those questions should be moved to Programmer's SE. Not closed, and not downvoted. The fact that many of them are not moved means that this is at least a grey area. If it is the right thing to do, why isn't it consistently done?

Comment: @FabioTurati why?  If the OP can't be bothered to pay attention to the rules of the site they are posting, when should we move the question around?  They asked the question, the onus is on them to know whether what they asked is on-topic?